# udev not running remove events

Tags: udev

I have two rules one for when a device, my phone, is connected and one for when it is disconnected.  The rule for add runs the remove rule does not.  Here is my udev rule.  I simplified but the remove event does not run.

```
#RUNS:
KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0ff9", SYMLINK+="phone", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/bin/touch /tmp/udev.add"
#DOES NOT RUN:
KERNEL=="sd?1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0ff9", SYMLINK+="phone", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/bin/touch /tmp/udev.remove"
```

Why would one run but not the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to refactor your removal rule as outlined here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/udev-not-doing-remove-rules-841733/

Summarizing the link content, it appears that once a device is removed, some of its attributes are not readable anymore so you will have to monitor the device removal and focus on the attributes that are dumped with `udevadm monitor --environment --udev`.

Also, creating a symlink during removal is plain wrong.

Comment: Silly copy and paste errors.  That was it.   It t should also note that the filtering is on environment variables with `ENV{VAR}==` instead of the `ATTRS{VAR}==` and the command above is how you can get the environment variables to filter on.  Thank you.